# New to linux server, about execute binaries with possibly different versions of MPI

Tags: linux, mpi, intel, hpc

I wrote and compilied some binaries and uploaded them to a linux server that operating on a remote supercomputer through SSH, if the binaries were compiled with, lets say, Intel's MPI libaries, but however if the remote linux server dont have the corresponding MPI lib installed over there, then will the binaries execute properly if I uploaded needed intel MPI dynamic-linking lib files to the linux server?

Comment: First blush says "yes" they would. Is it possible to static-link any external library functions so that you don't have this worry? (Of course, the binaries may need to be smaller.) I assume you won't have gcc library version issues as well.

Comment: @mrunion, no I dont have gcc library, I mostly work with Intel's library and compilers (both windows and linux), writing/debugging the codes in windows, then tunning, benchmarking and compiling the codes at a local linux workstation before upload the binaries to a remote supercomputer, and yes I may need to install all lib onto the remote supercomputer, the static-linked binaries will be quite large.

Comment: Why don't you simply transfer the code to the supercomputer and compile the binary there? Security reasons?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to compile the binaries on the target supercomputer machine (after you SSH). This way you're guaranteed that at least all the libraries are present at compile time, and if at all you would need to modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH to pick up the correct libraries.

Comment: Yes, I know that way, but the problem is the source codes will be open to be inspected by the super-users of the supercomputer, which is not allowed.

Comment: Then I would recommend to understand the configuration on the server (version of toolchain and other libraries for MPI), and try to replicate a similar setup on your side. This might get you closer to the target but still does not guarantee that you would be free of the dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes.

A few points

1. Many programs (MATLAB for example) will allow users to specify their own MPI library. Closed sourced programs should have an ability to specify their own MPI.
2. MPI is highly optimized for the cluster, it is often a selling point of the cluster.
3. Many clusters run in 2 modes, the optimized mode and a [Cluster Compatibility Mode](http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/hopper/cluster-compatibility-mode/). In the former only the vendor MPI runs, in the later OpenMPI and other MPIs are supported. For erudition, in the former many common `system()` calls can fail.

Comment: CCM is a Cray-specific mode, which means that not that many clusters run in 2 modes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work, have a look at Intel's [Redistributing Libraries When Deploying Applications](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/462704) document. Make also sure to use the compiler's cross-compile options to match the CPU architecture of the supercomputer.